# jquery conflict with another js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript

On my website I'm using [TafelTree](http://tafel.developpez.com/site/lang/en/doc.php) (a javascript that creates a collapsible tree menu). Recently I've made a widget using [jQuery Coundown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

My problem is that as long as my jQuery Countdown widget is in the page, the tree menu is no longer working (it doesn't display anything)

The call of the jQuery countdown function is:

```
$(function () {
       var theDay = new Date();
       theDay = new Date(2011, 9, 19, 20, 0, 0);
       $('#evo_defaultCountdown').countdown({until: theDay, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

The call of the TafelTree script is:

```
function TafelTreeInit () {
var struct = [{"id" : "item_280",
"txt" : '<a class="category-link">Back to School</a>',
"url" : "/back-to-school.html", "canhavechildren" : true,
"items" : [{
"id" : "item_280_277",
"txt" : '<a href="back-to-school/notebook-acer.html">notebook Acer</a>',
"canhavechildren" : false},{
"id" : "item_280_278",
"txt" : '<a href="back-to-school/desktop-monitor-acer.html">Desktop + monitor Acer </a>',
"canhavechildren" : false},{
"id" : "item_280_266",
"txt" : '<a href="back-to-school/pc-desktop-1.html">PC Desktop</a>',
"canhavechildren" : false},{
"id" : "item_280_267",
"txt" : '<a href="back-to-school/monitor.html">monitor</a>',
"canhavechildren" : false},{
"id" : "item_280_268",
"txt" : '<a href="back-to-school/laptop-mini-laptop.html">Laptop / Mini-laptop</a>',
"canhavechildren" : false},{
]}]; 
]}]; 
function funcOpen (item, response) {
   var selected = document.getElementById(item.idObj);
   var selectedParent = selected.parentNode;
   if(response == true) {
      selected.className = selected.className+' ' + selected.className + '_open';
      selectedParent.className = selectedParent.className+' ' + selectedParent.className + '_open';
      } else {
      selected.className  = 'tafelTreecontent';
      selectedParent.className = 'tafelTreecanvas';
      }
      return true;
      }

      tree = new TafelTree('menuHolder', struct, {
         'generate' : true,
         'imgBase' : SKIN_URL+'images/plugins/tree/',
          //'defaultImg' : 'page.gif',
          //'defaultImgOpen' : 'folderopen.gif',
          //'defaultImgClose' : 'folder.gif',
          'onLoad' : function(){},
          'onOpen' : funcOpen
       });

       if(tree.openAll == true || tree.openAll == 'open'){
            document.getElementById('nav_collapse').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('nav_expand').style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('nav_collapse').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('nav_expand').style.display = "block";
        }
}
```

Any idea what causes this conflict? How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen good point forgot to check that. I'm getting this error: `element.getInlineOpacity is not a function` but it's not relatet to the TafelTree script I think

Comment: Can I get a link or a jsFiddle? Need to see how you have done it all.

Comment: unfortunately the hole thing is on a local server and it's a nightmare to save the file and move all the references on a public server...

Comment: Okay, where do you call/start the funcOpen function?

Comment: sorry: there was another function within the function: I've edited my original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

in your case:

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
jQuery(function () {
       var theDay = new Date();
       theDay = new Date(2011, 9, 19, 20, 0, 0);
       jQuery('#evo_defaultCountdown').countdown({until: theDay, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

Comment: What do `"div p"` and `content` stand for? Also my jQuery function is after the other JS library on the page..

Comment: I think I confused the ideas, the first piece of code was a simple example of jquery code, it now eliminated! :D

Comment: thanks, that did the trick: now both the elements are displaying on the site, HOWEVER now the timer doesn't work (it doesn't display the digits)

Comment: I'm sorry but only with the javascript can not I be able to help: You can put an example of your situaizone [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: [here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JDTef/) You can notice in the javascript section that `jQuery.noConflict();` has been commented out and the timer works, if you uncomment it, it won't work anymore